# Proxies for IRC?

Tags: proxy, irc

There is this kid who joins IRC channels over and over after being banned.

Just wondering how he does this?  I tried to find a proxy list (to ban of course), but I don't know.

Let's put the ball in your court.  You get banned from an IRC on your normal IP (and normal AJAX IRC web clients like mibbit etc.), what do you do?

Answer (score 2):

You can do some things:

- Set the channel +i (require invitation)
- Set the channel +r (require services, account)

  - Then ban the account using extbans.
- Set +b on the nick it commonly uses.
- You can have a bot to detect spam and kickban the user.
- Try to ignore it, if you give it atention, he's goal will be acomplished.
- Ban it until he just stops.
- Use mode +m and only give voice (so they can talk) to users that are not evil.
- If you know his real IP, you can report him to his ISP.
- Ask network staff for help, they can help you ( for example, freenode has [Sigyn](https://github.com/freenode/Sigyn) ).

Also, you can't ban ALL they proxys because ban lists are not so long.

Answer (score 1):

> You get banned from an IRC on your normal IP (and normal AJAX IRC web
>   clients like mibbit etc.), what do you do?

I get an account at a VPN provider that has many IP addresses in many different countries. Odds are I can annoy you until my heart is content with the amount of IPs that most VPN providers have.

How do you solve this? Block him until he runs out of IP addresses and gets tired. This is a people issue, not a technical issue.